# VAR(2) model how to convert it to VEC(2) model

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model

I have the below VAR(2) model and I need to convert it into VEC representation how can I do it? Where can I find similar example or what is the way I should follow?

[image: Question]

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your VECM model as:

$\Delta y_t = \Pi y_{t-1} + \theta \Delta y_{t-1} + u_t $

$where, \Pi = (A_1 + A_2) - I,$

$ \theta = -A_2 $

The number of lags in VECM is one less than in VAR. In general, any VAR(p) can be specified as VECM:

$\Delta y_t = v + \Pi y_{t-1} + \sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\theta_i \Delta y_{t-i} + u_t $

$ where, \Pi = \sum_{j=1}^p A_j - I $

$ \theta_i = - \sum_{j=i+1}^p A_j $